# Akka Kafka restart on internal failure

Tags: apache-kafka, error-handling, akka, alpakka

I use the Alpakka Kafka connector for running a Consumer stream inside akka streams. The stream starts streams inside for each partition that is assigned to this consumer instance.
That means if there is any error inside a partition stream, then I need to restart either the partition or everything.

The code is following:

```
Consumer.DrainingControl<Done> control =
Consumer.committablePartitionedSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(topic))
    .mapAsyncUnordered(
        maxPartitions,
        pair -> {
          Source<ConsumerMessage.CommittableMessage<String, String>, NotUsed> source =
              pair.second();
          return source
              .via(businessThatMayCrash())
              .map(message -> message.committableOffset())
              .runWith(Committer.sink(committerSettings), system);
        })
    .toMat(Sink.ignore(), Consumer::createDrainingControl)
    .run(system);
```

See Separate streams per partition
https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/consumer.html#source-per-partition

But how I can restart the streams?
Please note: If there is any error on Kafka side, then it resumes automatically.

I tried to use the RestartSource for each partition but if the stream is failed then the Kafka consume does not work anymore.
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/RestartSource/onFailuresWithBackoff.html
Also `control.streamCompletion()` does not get completed.

There is also the option to add a `watchTermination()` for each partition that calls `control.drainAndShutdown(..)` but that seems quite complicated.
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/watchTermination.html

What is the best solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick will be to keep the failure of the stream you're running inside `mapAsyncUnordered` from failing the `mapAsyncUnordered`.

The easiest way to do this is to construct a `CompletableFuture` which will succeed when the stream succeeds or fails.

```java
// inside mapAsyncUnordered, apologies for any Java atrocities (Scala dev...)
pair -> {
  return
     pair.second()
        .via(businessLogicThatMayCrash())
        .map(message -> message.committableOffset())
        .runWith(Committer.sink(committerSettings), system)
        .handle((ignoredResult, ignoredFailure) -> akka.Done.done());
}
```

When the stream being run fails, a new source should be picked up by the `committablePartitionedSource`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Handling the exception works as expected.